# How do I combine 2 Select Queries

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

```
SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '".$id."' 

SELECT path FROM pokemons WHERE pk_id = '".$pkmn_id."'
```

I know I have to use JOIN, but I am not getting it right! 
How can I do that??

Comment: It's quite hard to tell without having an idea of your database schema... Indeed you will probably have to use JOIN somewehre...

Comment: So what _have_ you tried so far and what was wrong with those tries?

Comment: Perhaps you should start at the beginning. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp?PHPSESSID=300ae3404d5fa2612f238abeebb8869c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will return the path for every row in `user_pokemon_db` table.

```
SELECT p.path, upd.* 
FROM user_pokemon_db upd, pokemons p
WHERE upd.user_id = '".$id."' 
AND p.pk_id = '".$pkmn_id."'
```

Comment: This style would help me further :)

Answer (score 1):

If you expect both queries to return the same structure, you could use `UNION`.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

```
SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '".$id."' 
UNION
SELECT path FROM pokemons WHERE pk_id = '".$pkmn_id."'
```

Comment: That would expect both queries to return the same result structure. That most likely is _not_ the case!